# Creating threads in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsthread

I am trying to spawn a thread in swift. 
So I have this line:

.
.
.

```
let thread = NSThread(target: self, selector: doSomething(), object: nil)
```

.
.
.

doSomething is a function within the scope of the class.

That line gives this error:
"could not find an overload for init() that accepts the supplied arguments"

What am I missing here? Ho can I create a new thread in swift?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2, you can use the special form `#selector(...)`  where Objective-C would use `@selector(...)`:

```
let thread = NSThread(target:self, selector:#selector(doSomething), object:nil)
```

Comment: How would you do it if `doSomething` required an argument (say of type `NSString`)?

Comment: That is what the `object` argument is for.

Comment: I tried that, but I keep getting an `NSInvalidArgumentException`: `[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector`. It apparently doesn't recognize my function name. (Should I post this as a new question?)

Comment: If the selector takes an argument then it must end with a colon.  Example: `NSThread(target:self, selector:"doSomethingWithObject:", object:someObject)`

Comment: @Matt Make sure that your target class inherits from `NSObject`.

Comment: @kaolick doesn't every class automatically inherit from `NSObject`?

Comment: @Matt Possibly not. I had the same problem that you mentioned above. I could only solve it by letting my class inherit from NSObject. To my excuse I should mention that this was my first try with Swift though...

Comment: No, classes don't inherit from `NSObject` by default. If you make a subclass of anything in the Cocoa Touch frameworks, it will inherit `NSObject` indirectly. Otherwise, in Swift, you need to explicitly inherit from `NSObject`, or declare your class `@objc`, in order to use it with `NSThread`.

Comment: In Swift 2.2, you now use #selector(doSomething).

Answer (score 4):

NSThread takes a selector as it's second parameter. You can describe Objective-C selectors as Strings in Swift like this:

```
let thread = NSThread(target: myObj, selector: "mySelector", object: nil)
```

Swift functions aren't equivalent objective-c methods though. If you have a method in a swift class, you can use it as a selector if you use the @objc attribute on the class:

```
@objc class myClass{
    func myFunc(){
    }
}

var myObj = myClass()
let thread = NSThread(target: myObj, selector: "myFunc", object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When we call a selector on a target, we should check if the target exists and it responds to the selector. Only class that extend from `NSObject` or it's subclasses can use `respondsToSelector:`
2. You can use a `NSDictionary` to store parameters if you have more than 2 parameters.

   Ex:

   ```
   //this code is in Objective-C but the same code should exist in Swift

   NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:object1, @"key1", object2, @"key2",nil];
   ```

then pass 'params' to parameter of selector: